# Excel VBA: Multiple Criteria Match - Evaluate Function

Tags: vba, excel

I have tried on several occasions to correctly use the evaluate function in VBA, but I have not been successful. I want to run a multiple criteria match on a data table. I have provided a sample data table here for testing. I cannot get the function `Evaluate(evalStr)` to pass a match row. I repeatedly get an error message. I have provided a sample set of code below, the desired result is row 7 where item1 = "Orange" and item2 = "Feb". Can you please help in identifying the issue?

[image]

```
Sub testEval()

Dim dataTable As ListObject
Dim evalStr As Variant
Dim item1 As String
Dim item2 As String
Dim ws As Worksheet

item1 = "Orange"
item2 = "Feb"

Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set dataTable = ws.ListObjects(1)

With ws

    'V1
    evalStr = .Evaluate("MATCH(" & item1 & "&" & item2 & "," & .Columns(1).Address & "&" & .Columns(2).Address & "),0)")

    'V2?
    'evalStr = .Evaluate("MATCH(" & item1 & "&" & item2 & "," & Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Columns(1).Address & "&" & .Columns(2).Address, "$", "") & "),0)"

    'With dataTable.DataBodyRange

        ''V3?
        'evalStr = ws.Evaluate("MATCH(" & item1 & "&" & item2 & "," & .Columns(1).Address & "&" & .Columns(2).Address & "),0)")

        ''V4?
        'evalStr = ws.Evaluate("MATCH(" & item1 & "&" & item2 & "," & Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Columns(1).Address & "&" & .Columns(2).Address, "$", "") & "),0)")

    'End With

    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`evalStr` should be:

```
evalStr = .Evaluate("=MATCH(""" & item1 & """&""" & item2 & """," & .Columns(1).Address & "&" & .Columns(2).Address & ",0)")
```

`=` is missing from formula, `item1` and `item2` should be enclosed in double quotes hence I've added `""` and there's extra `)` before `,0`

Comment: Every single example of this has left out the "=" sign before match... I have also tried the escaping the quotes too, just not in conjunction with the = sign. Your answer was correct. Thank you

Comment: @Citanaf please mark the answer as described in the [Tour].

Comment: @teylyn I was waiting for the minimum amount of time to expire before I could. Thanks

Comment: Ah, I see. I wasn't aware of that time limit.